# ffmpeg is not able to parse DASH-IF manifest

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I tried [manifest](https://delta9tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/2057298.mpd) from local tv channel provider. It's live stream but somehow ffmpeg is not able to parse the manifest.

Command :

```sh
ffmpeg -i "https://delta9tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/2057298.mpd" -c copy -f mp4 /tmp/out.mp4
```

It's encrypted with widevine DRM. But that's not important. ffmpeg is complaining about input data.

Error :

```sh
[dash @ 0x55d605e25100] Unable to read to manifest 'https://delta9tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/2057298.mpd'
https://delta9tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/2057298.mpd: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Upgrade and check. The manifest can be parsed here.

Comment: @Gyan Using ffmpeg version 4.3.1-4ubuntu1. are you talking about unstable release ?

Comment: Yes, the latest git build - it's not unstable.

Comment: Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://delta9tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/2057298.mpd" on this server.
Reference #18.5dd3717.1607892411.1054a36b